# Expressjs showing same data to all users

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express, filesystems

i have been making simple file sharing system on express where i list all the files of directory and when user clicks to the file it get downloaded ..
it is working but when some other user visit same route from another machine then he also get the same directory listing which previous user has selected.

Also when page is been reloaded same data is shown but what i want is for every new user default directory's listing should be done not what other user has selected in other machine.

Demo : https://samundrakapp.herokuapp.com/home

Code : https://github.com/samundrak/quicksharejs

Answer (score 0):

I guess that https://github.com/samundrak/quicksharejs/blob/master/routes/QuickShare.js acts as a singleton?

Comment: in quickshare object instead of this i have used object name to access properties do it matters?